# open android app from a redirect and not a link

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having an issue with trying deep links and getting my app to open. I have the following code which is way for me to determine if I have a ios user or android. If it is android then I want to redirect the user to open their app if installed.

The problem is that the redirect to `company://open.me/` is not opening the app

If I create a manual link like

```
<a href="company://open.me/">Open Me</a>
```

This works fine and opens my app.

Any help?

```
<script>
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    location.replace("company://");
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!document.webkitHidden) {
            location.replace("https://www.company.com");
        }
    }, 25);
} else if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i))) {
    window.location = "company://open.me/";
} else {
    location.replace("https://www.company.com");
}
</script>
```

**Manifest**

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="company" android:host="open.me" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Try using `window.open("company://open.me/");`

Comment: Didn't work, tried that too anyways

Comment: How about trying `location.href = "company://open.me/";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `“intent:”` syntax described in this article.
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

The basic syntax for an intent-based URI is as follows:

```
intent:
   HOST/URI-path // Optional host 
   #Intent; 
      package=[string]; 
      action=[string]; 
      category=[string]; 
      component=[string]; 
      scheme=[string]; 
   end;
```

Comment: I already tried this as well. Setup my intent-filter. Same results works if I create a `<a>` and click on it, but not as a redirect

Comment: I even tried using a `S.browser_fallback_url` with it to see if that would redirect to my app in the app store and it does not fire so it must think I have the app still but for whatever reason does not open the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change how you call window.location.

This will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
function newDoc() {
  window.location.assign("company://open.me/")
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="company://open.me/">deep link</a>

<input type="button" value="Load new document" onclick="newDoc()">
  </body>
</html>
```